# Incompatible packages in conda - error occurs during mamba env create command

Tags: conda, mamba

For a long time, a project has been installing packages with `mamba env create --file environment.yaml`. Suddenly, from one day to another, environment stopped working and started throwing below error. What's the cause and how to fix it?

```bash
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ fastapi 0.92  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ marshmallow-dataclass 8.5.14  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
└─ streamlit 1.23.1  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel).
The command '/bin/sh -c mamba env create --file environment.yaml' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Sometimes package builds get marked as broken, which takes them off the default `repodata.json`. There are ways to include searching the `broken` subdirectory, but it's tricky to do correctly, so I don't recommend it. A more reliable solution these days is [`conda-lock`](https://conda.github.io/conda-lock/), which records actual URLs. You get the added benefit of lockfiles being pre-solved, so you'll get faster setup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **missing patch version** in `environment.yaml` file. Project referred package `fastapi==0.92` without patch version. Updating package to latest (`0.97.0`) with patch `0` (major.minor.patch) fixed it!